# How to devise correct code to normalize matrix of gene expression values?

Tags: r, normalization

Prior to calculating a PCA, I need to normalize my data. I have a matrix where the row names represent the disease group ( 0 represents control, 1 is Ulcerative Colitis and 2 is Crohn's). The rest of the data represents gene expression values.

Here is my data;

```
       structure(c(5.54e-05, 5.58e-06, 9.74e-05, 1.33e-06, 1.29e-05, 
       7.22e-06, 0.000215899, 3.6e-06, 0.000146724, 1.53e-05, 0.000913187, 
       1.9e-06, 0.007421464, 0.000648006, 5.1e-06, 6.15e-06, 4.73e-06, 
       0.000119899, 0.000884487, 0.000850632, 0.000236607, 7.36e-06, 
       8.48e-06, 2.63e-05, 0.001368493, 1.12e-05, 0.000177568, 0.006338532, 
       0.006162866, 0.040695132, 0.013255055, 0.033086619, 0.074158811, 
       0.004967497, 0.01247423, 0.043201417, 0.011470285, 0.038447751, 
       0.018825124, 0.027701807, 0.063373762, 0.005374513, 0.048876252, 
       0.009959848, 0.004434078, 0.004176856, 0.015288913, 0.060226053, 
       0.05128922, 0.006557554, 0.017460326, 0.007684784, 0.002107577, 
       0.005773192, 0.076186393, 0.037631043, 0.052159393, 0.012179365, 
       0.047199766, 0.022458838, 0.030261613, 0.00626629, 0.028664896, 
       0.02285845, 0.02801855, 0.017681676, 0.040563592, 0.029791175, 
       0.034778056, 0.019318473, 0.011847912, 0.009614177, 0.064027542, 
       0.035334149, 0.041638955, 0.056015014, 0.03304865, 0.017660205, 
       0.030187166, 0.057919531, 0.029990489, 0.000112884, 0.000920886, 
       0.001081748, 0.000195159, 0.001678445, 0.000171612, 0.000191702, 
       0.000560035, 0.000384056, 0.000454783, 0.000723385, 0.000203897, 
       0.000973337, 0.000822171, 0.000620526, 0.000260769, 0.000214607, 
       0.002077443, 0.00065843, 0.000403672, 0.000378651, 0.000409306, 
       0.001722587, 0.000213785, 0.000176643, 0.002022878, 0.001886929, 
       0.053029236, 0.022594965, 0.011967636, 0.026851113, 0.03773798, 
       0.031356268, 0.10410326, 0.063265216, 0.018028454, 0.116038001, 
       0.00572817, 0.053635968, 0.059126941, 0.011835241, 0.004639624, 
       0.014302911, 0.082948853, 0.015202238, 0.021295431, 0.043342, 
       0.008153675, 0.015613747, 0.043289609, 0.048834321, 0.019144763, 
       0.059809871, 0.006990685, 0.04082966, 0.02986135, 0.061405171, 
       0.006142619, 0.009767602, 0.035427993, 0.03729329, 0.01309739, 
       0.00221718, 0.040211393, 0.006303841, 0.030146612, 0.032033879, 
       0.024590398, 0.077991721, 0.017215666, 0.014731147, 0.04802582, 
       0.03168714, 0.03244771, 0.032278613, 0.017301885, 0.013450667, 
       0.040207755, 0.042669615, 0.03456749, 0.034631319, 1.93e-05, 
       4.72e-06, 5.41e-05, 0, 1.91e-05, 9.33e-07, 5.98e-06, 0, 1.05e-06, 
       4.1e-07, 7.72e-05, 4.07e-07, 0.000585154, 0.000246992, 7.86e-06, 
       3.13e-06, 2.14e-06, 7.56e-06, 9.29e-05, 0.000116024, 5.51e-05, 
       7.79e-06, 6.65e-06, 2.06e-06, 0.000104342, 4.16e-06, 1.27e-05, 
       0.000197502, 0.00015135, 0.000107306, 6.54e-05, 0.000225564, 
       0.000142631, 0.000168873, 3.5e-05, 0.000365242, 0.000174254, 
       0.000339327, 8.7e-05, 0.000136679, 0.000156634, 0.000224181, 
       0.000205305, 8.87e-05, 0.000305774, 0.000133615, 0.00015118, 
       0.000107229, 0.000162579, 0.000152249, 6.88e-05, 0.000113864, 
       0.000249258, 0.00024256, 0.00079296, 0.007640951, 0.004937327, 
       0.000422361, 0.000953513, 0.000951187, 0.000671306, 0.001106406, 
       0.002606568, 0.003006867, 0.001911646, 0.00135411, 0.012461738, 
       0.000434917, 0.00237646, 0.007857561, 0.000436889, 0.00048816, 
       0.000348146, 0.000931449, 0.000323974, 0.004945321, 0.000693845, 
       0.000479572, 0.000843415, 0.001419675, 0.001547478, 8.16e-05, 
       6.63e-05, 0.000101583, 3.08e-05, 0.000147039, 5.13e-05, 0.000109479, 
       2.39e-05, 0.000225475, 4.28e-05, 0.000230785, 2.1e-05, 0.0001356, 
       0.000124173, 0.000245128, 0.000275446, 3.18e-05, 0.00017516, 
       0.000180192, 0.000246669, 0.000378708, 4.35e-05, 0.000267824, 
       7.2e-05, 7.65e-05, 8.79e-05, 0.000130026, 0.000111462, 3.17e-05, 
       0.000200096, 3.12e-06, 8.75e-05, 3.11e-06, 6.89e-06, 0.000165936, 
       5.98e-05, 0.000201355, 5.92e-06, 2.57e-05, 2.53e-05, 3.27e-05, 
       0.000137446, 0.000134402, 5.86e-07, 3.9e-05, 0.018886909, 0.050343466, 
       4.15e-05, 1.67e-05, 0.000172614, 4.95e-05, 1.27e-05, 9.85e-05, 
       4.28e-05, 0.002708402, 0.003215586, 0.00457116, 0.001713549, 
       0.024353184, 0.006660748, 0.003198887, 0.003094386, 0.004789163, 
       0.002816955, 0.021587313, 0.002084725, 0.00378062, 0.021751495, 
       0.009097143, 0.012216225, 0.001125765, 0.013043534, 0.005514773, 
       0.008323962, 0.026898764, 0.002149135, 0.008021623, 0.006673567, 
       0.005391139, 0.018578559, 0.013786297, 0.00080595, 0.001289505, 
       0.002451416, 0.000234107, 0.001694733, 0.000288175, 0.002357478, 
       0.000856129, 0.00159752, 0.000117538, 0.000166581, 0.000367288, 
       0.001039841, 0.001779528, 0.000438092, 0.001012515, 0.000529936, 
       0.003193086, 0.002562702, 0.00277401, 0.003013136, 0.001349197, 
       0.001646296, 0.001114222, 0.001207882, 0.002804949, 0.000366419
       ), .Dim = c(27L, 13L), .Dimnames = list(c("2", "0", "0", "0", 
      "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "2", "0", "0", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
      "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "0", "0"), c("Gene1", 
      "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", 
      "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", "Gene12", "Gene13")))
```

The real dataset is a lot larger with 194 rows and 600 genes. I do have 0's in my data. I have attempted log-transform (through adding a very small number to the data points, which I understand is not the best), BoxCox using the caret package and qqnorm. None of these methods have made the data fit a normal distribution as determined through histogram plots of some of the columns, the Anderson-Darling tests or QQ plots where appropriate.

I understand I can try the Yeo Johnson method via the Caret or bestNormalize package, given that I have zero values.

The code I have tried so far is this, and the data points are not transformed with YeoJohnson using the caret package. There is no error message.

```
      require(caret)

      preProcessValues <- preProcess(data, method = "YeoJohnson")


      datanorm <- predict(preProcessValues, data)
```

datanorm values are still the same as the original data.

Other methods I have tried would be qqnorm(data), which does not normalise when looking at the output values.

Update; I understand from the comments below that Z score normalisation will not be helpful to ensure that the data fits a normal distribution.

Any suggestions as to how to correct the above would be beneficial please, as this is the only package whereby I can input the data as a matrix.

The bestNormalize package can only be used on individual columns ( as x must be a vector), and I need the transformation ideally on the matrix of values.

```
       require(bestNormalize)

       values <- yeojohnson(data[, 1], standardize=T)
       normoutput <-predict(values)
```

Comment: It's not topically helpful to just say sometime didn't work. The methods you describe should work. Tell us what happens that prevents them from working because unless you do that my assumption is just that you did it wrong.

Comment: also scaling the data (subtracting the mean and dividing by sd) will not  make *the data fit a normal distribution* (unless it was normal to begin with)

Comment: user20650 is correct, scaling & centering does not make a distribution normal, and that is not the point of doing so prior to modeling. It is typically used to account for order of magnitudes differences in your data to allow variables to assume their true importance. If you have skewing that is problematic, your options should be some kind of transformation, whether that is a log or root or exponential of some kind, or box-cox ....however if you have negative values the Yeo-Johnson is a consistently good method, and my experience with caret it that it works very well.

Comment: @sconfluentus thank you for your comments. Please find above an edited question and the code that I have tried to run the YeoJohnson transformation using the caret package, which isn't currently working. Any advice on how to make it work would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While as you said, bestNormalize must take only a vector, you can use a loop to run bestNormalize on each column individually, this may be what you are looking for. Here is another post that implements this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60592624/12777743